# What is the initial acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

What is the initial acceleration of mass 5M .The pulleys are ideal and the string inextensible.

[image]

My attempt-

2Mg-T=2Ma    (for 2M)

T=Ma         (for M)

Solving we get T=2Mg/3

T-N=5MA      (for 5M)

N=2MA        (for 2M)

Solving we get A=2g/21
but the given ans. is 2g/23

Comment: helpful--http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This question _does_ show some effort. It shouldn't be locked.

Comment: @user5061 please note that showing effort is not sufficient reason to reopen the question. (It's not _locked_, it's on hold.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how you get your equation: T-N=5MA 
But I would state that, because there are no horizontal external forces, then the center of mass must not move in the horizontal direction, that is:
$(7MA)-Ma=0 $
from this and your equation for $a=T/M=2g/3$, you easily get A